# How to increase connection per host while cassandra streaming

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

While I am running nodetool decommission, I want to use 100% of my network. I set "nodetool setstreamthroughput 0". At the beginning, since the node on which decommission process started sends multiple nodes, The node can send data at speed 900Mbps. Later, since number of nodes that transferred is reducing, the node can send data like 300Mbps.

I see that the node sends one SSTable to one node. I want to increase the parallelism. nodetool says that one connection per hosts. How can I increase this setting. I mean "multiple connection per hosts" while I am streaming?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely Cassandra 3.0 will not be able to utilize 100% of your network regardless of how you set it up. Even with multiple threads you push up against a point where the allocation rate of objects generated in the streaming will exceed what the jvm can clean up and then your GC pauses will only be able give you 100% for short periods. Kind of moot though as you cannot configure it to use more threads.

In cassandra 4.0 you will be able to achieve this: http://cassandra.apache.org/blog/2018/08/07/faster_streaming_in_cassandra.html